# Feature parameters and FeatureManagement class in salesforce

Tags: apex

What are feature parameters in Salesforce and when do we use it? Also, what is the use of FeatureManagement class? I read the documentation, but couldn't understand their use. Can anyone help in understanding this concept?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an ISV, you use features to enable, disable, and/or customize features in your application. You can use LMO-to-subscriber features to push settings to the app (e.g. such as enabling premium features, enhanced reporting, etc), and you can use subscriber-to-LMO features to collect usage metrics. You can also use the changeProtection method to show or hide custom permissions and custom objects (with some limitations on custom objects). If you're not packaging on the AppExchange, this class and its related features probably have no use for you, so you can safely ignore them, except possibly checkPermission, which is a handy way of seeing if the current user has a Custom Permission enabled on their profile or through a Permissioon Set without having to use a query.

---

- ISV: An Independent Software Vendor that provides solutions on the AppExchange or other delivery mechanisms.
- LMA: The License Management App is installed by ISVs to monitor subscribers, chance their licenses, and use the Login Access feature.
- LMO: The License Management Org is the org in which the LMA is installed. You can send data to and from the LMO to a subscriber using FeatureManagement methods and the configured fields on the License object in the LMA.

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks for explaining so well..!